# Microsoft Graph subscription notifications not being pushed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Been working with subscriptions for the past few months and haven't had issues. Today our service has been down because changes made for Contacts and Events are not issuing a notification to our API. I have resubscribed several times in different environments to no avail. Code base has not changed for the past couple days.

The URL for the `POST` is: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions`

This is the request payload (2018-12-13T14:40:48.321209 PST):

`{
:changeType=>"created,updated", :notificationUrl=>"https://da532483.ngrok.io/office365/subscription/notification", :resource=>"/me/calendars/AQMkADAwATY3ZmYAZS1lZmRkAC1lOTZhLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA6PhSGdMGt9Nkwdvvtt9NrIHAD-_YGH8PpRIvfFpb45sC10AAAIBBgAAAD-_YGH8PpRIvfFpb45sC10AAtZPfToAAAA=/events", 
:expirationDateTime=>"2018-12-16T21:10:48+00:00", 
:clientState=>"clientState"
}`

And the response payload (2018-12-13T14:40:49.339139 PST):

`{
"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
"id":"d07de8ab-2c6c-447c-90d1-2b583318c597",
"resource":"/me/calendars/AQMkADAwATY3ZmYAZS1lZmRkAC1lOTZhLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA6PhSGdMGt9Nkwdvvtt9NrIHAD-_YGH8PpRIvfFpb45sC10AAAIBBgAAAD-_YGH8PpRIvfFpb45sC10AAtZPfToAAAA=/events",
"applicationId":"0e8eebe4-55dc-4bd6-91ac-c13f91bb145d",
"changeType":"created,updated",
"clientState":"clientState",
"notificationUrl":"https://da532483.ngrok.io/office365/subscription/notification",
"expirationDateTime":"2018-12-16T21:10:48Z",
"creatorId":"00067FFEEFDDE96A"
}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the issues you experienced with Microsoft Graph webhook notifications.

**Here is what happened:**

We experienced a capacity issue that resulted in a delayed deliveries for a subset of notifications. Some subscriptions were affected more than others, with some subscribers seeing a significant drop in notifications delivered. The time period for this issue was between 2AM on 12-12-2018 and 6PM 12-13-2018 (PST).

**What we are going to do:**

1.We are investigating the root cause and will take steps to prevent this from occurring in the future.

2.We recognize that our outage communications for Graph notifications are lacking. We are working on improving our comms with the goal of pro-actively publishing service degradation info to our customers as soon as we realize they occur.

We appreciate your usage of Graph and our webhook notification framework. Sorry about the trouble!

Comment: Thanks for the response!!